# Underlying vector space for the Lie algebra of $U(n)$ and for $C_2 \ltimes U(n)$.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semidirect-product

The Lie algebra of $U(n)$ is given by $n \times n$ skew-Hermitian matrices, with the bracket given by the usual commutator $[A,B] = AB- BA$.

I'm curious what the Lie algebra of $C_2 \ltimes U(n)$ is. In particular, I want to understand the underlying vector space of this Lie algebra, to better understand the adjoint representations of these compact Lie groups.

Does the short exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow U(n) \rightarrow C_2 \ltimes U(n) \rightarrow C_2
$$
induce a short exact sequence of lie algebras? And if so, does this yield that the underlying vector space for the Lie algebra of $C_2 \ltimes U(n)$ is the underlying vector space of the Lie algebra of $U(n)$, since the Lie algebra of $C_2$ is zero-dimensional?

Comment: Put another way, the Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$ depends only on the identity connected component of $G$.

Comment: @Kajelad thanks, I wasn't aware of this face. Do you happen to have a reference?

Comment: It follows from the identification of the Lie algebra with the tangent space at the identity $\mathfrak{g}\cong T_eG$. This is covered in chapter 8 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, among other places.